# Can we build install shield - Install script / Install script MSI project to generate 64-bit setup.exe?

Tags: installshield, installscript, installshield-2018

I want to know whether it is possible to create setup.exe (64-bit) from install shield. 
I have read following things to do this, but nothing worked :
https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Forum/64-bit-Setup-Isntallation/m-p/55761#M33183

http://www.installationdeveloper.com/2169/how-to-create-a-pure-64-bit-installation-in-installshield/

Actually I'm not able to load the 64-bit dll into 32-bit installer(using UseDLL() ), following is the reason for that, so I want to build 64-bit setup.exe, which might load my 64-bit dll.
https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Knowledge/Can-I-Load-64-bit-DLL-Files-in-InstallScript/ta-p/3819

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Script Project is still 32-bit(in Install Shield 2020), They are supporting MSI project as 64-bit (from Install Shield 2020). So we can not build installer as 64-bit from Installer script Project.

Answer (score 1):

UseDLL is part of InstallScript. InstallShield Installscript engine supports only 32 bit dlls as of now. So, UseDLL does not load x64 DLLs.